Safari cutting off text when using column-count and flexbox together
When I use column-count and display: flex I get odd results in Safari - the content becomes a jumbled mess.
Here is my code:


.container {
  column-count: 4;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      left
    </div>
    <div>
      right
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      left
    </div>
    <div>
      right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



For those not using Safari, here is what the output looks like in Safari:

Here is the output in Chrome:

It appears that Safari tries to add the maximum number of columns that I have specified (4) and so it splits the two content containers in half. Is there a way to make this work in Safari short of using JavaScript to calculate the column-count?

I don’t have a full explanation, but it’s almost as if Safari is using contents instead of flex.
A hack which works for your example code (tested on Safari/IOS17…) is to use inline-flex. That seems to fool it into realizing it’s just one element not two.
Whether this will work in whatever your general case is, I don’t of course know. You’ll have to try it.


.container {
  column-count: 4;
}

.row {
    display: inline-flex;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      left
    </div>
    <div>
      right
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      left
    </div>
    <div>
      right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Definitely hacky but it works, thank you! I will be opening a bug with Safari as well.
